# How to know whether BIOS has turned on the processor's Virtualization Technology or not?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, bios, microsoft-virtual-pc

My BIOS does not have any option to show / modify virtualization technology (VT).

Although my processor supports VT, I am not sure whether it is turned on in BIOS.

Is there any utility which can show whether virtualization is ON or not?

Comment: The linux variant of this question: [How to detect if VT-X has been turned on in the BIOS?](http://superuser.com/q/567208/102047)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've tagged the question with VirtualBox, start up a VM and check if this box below is highlighted:

[image]

This will show if VT is enabled.

Comment: Not a definitive check - what if VT is disabled in the VM's options?

Comment: True, but AFAIK VT is enabled by default in VB so unless this has been disabled by the user this is a reasonably good indicator.

Answer (score -3):

Yes and if you bothered to Google ["windows check vt"](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+check+vt) you could have figured out how:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/securable-detects-cpu-processor-security-features-bit-lenght-dep-and-virtualization/

Comment: More Googling shows you how to find it whether you're running on Linux or Windows http://kb.parallels.com/6686