# How to detect if VT-X has been turned on in the BIOS?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vt-x

I know I can check is VT-X is *supported* by a processor by `egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`. But even if it's supported, it can be turned off in the BIOS. How can I detect if it's turned on or off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VT-X information is stored in [model-specific registers (MSR) 0x34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register) which can be accessed via `msr-tools`. Install it by running `sudo apt-get install msr-tools` then run the following commands

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr 0x3A
```

If the return value is 3, 5 or 7 then VT-X is enabled

See [Reliably detecting if Intel VT is disabled in the BIOS](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2007-March/msg00218.html)

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 I had to install `kmod` instead.  `msr-tools` did not contain `modprobe`.  `modprobe msr` also wasn't able to run:  "modprobe: FATAL: Module msr not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic"

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to verify:

1. On Debian-based distros (such as Ubuntu), you can check support for VT-x by installing `cpu-checker` and run `kvm-ok` with sudo rights.

   If the CPU is enabled, you should see something like:

   ```
    INFO: /dev/kvm exists
    KVM acceleration can be used
   ```

   Otherwise, you'll get:

   ```
    INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
    HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
    INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
    INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
    HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
       and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
    KVM acceleration can NOT be used
   ```
2. On Debian-based and RHEL-based systems, you can use `virt-host-validate` which is provided by the `libvirt-client` package. Documentation on usage can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-host-validate).

Answer (score 0):

A very unenviable way to check (without going into the BIOS) would be to install/open Virtualbox hypervisor, and try installing a 64-bit Linux VM and see if the settings allow you to enable VT-X. Installation of VM in virtualbox is the only context where I've encountered the need to enable VT-X/AMD-V.